# How to solve in principle such coupled ODEs

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

One example for coupled ODEs from the Mathemtica help center reads

```
a = NDSolve[{x'[t] == -3 (x[t] - y[t]), 
    y'[t] == -x[t] z[t] + 26.5 x[t] - y[t], 
    z'[t] == x[t] y[t] - z[t], x[0] == z[0] == 0, 
    y[0] == 1}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 5}]
```

Now we can for example extend this expression by replacing

```
x'[t] == -3 (x[t] - y[t]) -> x['t] == -3* (x[t] - y[t])*int[t]
```

with

```
f[t_] := Sin[t^2]
int[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Exp[-f[t]]*v^2, {v, 0, 1}]
```

This works indeed fine, but now I would like to extend the integral expression further by making the integrand dependent on the current solution of z[t] i.e.

```
int[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Exp[-f[t]*Evaluate[z[t]/.a]*v^2], {v, 0, 1}]
```

But this expression returns a bunch of errors. Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: But neither `z` nor `f` are dependent on `v`, no?

Comment: Right, they are both independent

Comment: Then you can factor them out of the integral, no?

Comment: Thats not trivial if one has e.g. Sinh[f[t]*z[t]*v] as integrand

Comment: You probably should have used that example, then. :)

Comment: I changed the example. Anyway, do you have an idea?

Comment: `int[0.1]` gives me no errors. Could you indicate what code produces what errors? (Including both provides clues to the problem.)

Comment: I get the errors  **ReplaceAll::reps**. And also for `int[0.1]` I get an error, saying extrapolation will be used

Comment: I used this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/WFr6v.png -- Perhaps it's not the code you used. I'm not sure I understood what you meant by "extend this expression...." -- `ReplaceAll::reps` suggests `NDSolve[]` was unsuccessful or that `a` is somehow corrupted.  `InterpolatingFunction::dmval` indicates you have an `InterpolatingFunction` but it is not defined over a domain containing `t == 0.1` (or your code got corrupted). You can examine these things: `?a`, `?int`, etc. (Use @username to notify a user; authors of posts are always notified of comments.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think substituting `a` in the definition of `int`, which is called by `a` is trouble, and what you really need is to make sure `int` isn't evaluated when `z[t]` isn't a number.  The following seems to work, albeit not very quickly:

```
Clear[a];

f[t_] := Sin[t^2];
int[t_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Exp[-f[t]*z*v^2], {v, 0, 1}];

a = NDSolve[{
  x'[t] == -3*(x[t] - y[t])*int[t, z[t]], 
  y'[t] == -x[t] z[t] + 26.5 x[t] - y[t],
  z'[t] == x[t] y[t] - z[t], 
  x[0] == z[0] == 0, y[0] == 1},
  {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 5}]
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for, works fine! However, adding to the above definition of `int[t,z]` the new def. `int2[t_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 
 h[1] /. NDSolve[{h'[v] == Exp[-f[t]*z*v^2], h[0] == 0}, 
   h, {v, 0, 1}]` and calling `int2[t,z[t]]` in NDSolve produces fatal errors, even though `Plot[{int[t, 1], int2[t, 1]}, {t, 0, 5}]` shows the same result. Do you know how to do the replacement right?

Comment: `int2[2, 1]` gives  `{1.32159}` not `1.32159` -- you have to strip off a level with `[[1]]`.  That is, `int2[t_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := h[1] /. NDSolve[{h'[v] == Exp[-f[t]*z*v^2], h[0] == 0}, h, {v, 0, 1}][[1]]` works